# How to implement Push notifications

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, push-notification, signalr

I need to implement push notification in my application, whenever a table gets updated by other user(updating some records through UI).

I have been googling from the morning,but I cant able to proceed further.

I have found some recommendations to use sqlDependency class with SignalR if its SQL server, but I'm not using SQL server.

kindly suggest me, how to implement in my application.

Comment: The key phrase to google for is 'PostgreSQL NOTIFY / LISTEN'.
1. PostgreSQL part: create triggers that emit notifications
2. Backend part: create a daemon which connects to db and listens to notifications

Comment: U can read here about database triggers: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_triggers.htm

Comment: you mean triggers will call the C# methods ?@pumbo

Comment: @King_Fisher Not directly, but yes. A trigger will emit postgresql notification (via `NOTIFY` command), then your C# program (which will be listening to notifications via postgresql `LISTEN` command) will receive it and will execute appropriate C# method.

Comment: How C# methods will update to client scripts to display in UI ? @pumbo

Comment: @King_Fisher In javascript you basically have 2 options: 1) do periodic ajax-request to obtain updates 2) (preferable) use websocket connection. So, on backend you have to build either a websocket app, or classic web-program. It's too big thing to describe shortly. Just google for these things.

Comment: Depends on whether you want a database solution or a code solution. SignalR should do the trick if you want to solve this in code.

Comment: Try call from  controller.

Comment: means ?  @ArchilLabadze

Comment: For example when I want to push notifcation from  my controller I'm using context: here is part of code. var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>(); context.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);